# Where should authored code be stored on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, file-location

Previously, I kept authored code in a folder inside `Program Files`.
By "code" I mean any kind of code you, as a programmer, would write.

However, with the new permission model in Windows 8.1, storing files there requires elevated sessions for PowerShell (for example) when running commands that change folder contents (file removal, edits, creation).

As such, where would a good place to store code be?
The Unix model would suggest to store it under your user documents, `~/user/username/documents/`.

Any suggestions for Windows systems?

**EDIT:** Hopefully, made the question clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by "code"? I'm a software developer and to me, "code" means "uncompiled source code". I'd never store that in Program Files, nor would I store it in ~/user/username/documents, so perhaps I'm confused.

Comment: i see nothing wrong with `C:\Users\You\`. This is the place where you have access rights by design. If you are using system that you share with others, keep your stuff under mentioned path. If you are and admin and the computer is private, use any path you want outside of the system restricted directories.

Comment: `Code` means anything you author, uncompiled if it's a language that requires compilation for example.

Comment: What bothers me about `C:\Users\You` is that's where crap like Microsoft pictures, and Games are automatically created. It's sort of like a place where there's junk created by the OS and other apps, to me anyway.

Comment: It seems that your "code" is referring to powershell, bash or cmd scripts. You can put them where you like. How about `%USERPROFILE%\documents\scripts`?

Comment: That's not true, PowerShell and bash are mentioned as things that perform actions on folders.

Comment: I tend to use c:\source so that in the rare cases where a fully qualified path is required it evaluates the same on each team members box, and is easy to access. We do occasionally have trouble when a teammate puts their code within their profile, and isn't careful about how they handle pathing when submitting the code to source control for other developers to access. Additionally only certian user accounts may be used to merge to specific branches (like release) and in that case the developer must access their code under a differant user account, so user isolated storage is an impediment.

Comment: To be fair, you have had to elevate permissions when running something out of Program Files, since Windows Vista not just Windows 8.1.

Comment: Yeah, but using the RunAs dialog would start any program with Admin privileges.